# Change query param in url using UI-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router how can I accomplish the following URL change? For example, when a user goes to "/page?hello=True" I want the url to change to "/page?status=hello".

```
$stateProvider.state('page', {
   url: '/page/:id?status',
   controller: 'MyCtrl as myCtrl',
   templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
     return $templateCache.get('templates/route.html');
   }
 });
```

Comment: can use `stateChangeStart` event in ui-router to change the params of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stateChangeStart` event in the app.run method to listen for state changes into that route, and change anything you want on the params. Something like this, might need to play with `toState` and `toParams` to get it right for you...

```
.run(['$state', '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        if (toState.name === 'invitation') {
            //change toParams to whatever you want 
        }
    });
});
```